# Integrate cos (lnx) dx

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrating by parts:

I'm having a hard time choosing the $u$, $du$, $v$ and $dv$...
I gave it a shot.

$u = \ln x \implies du = 1/x \ dx$

$v= \  ?$
$dv =  \cos \ dx$

Comment: Expand into two power function terms using the complex definition of $\cos(x)$, use power rule, and convert back.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Choose $u = \cos\log x$ and $dv = dx$.

$$\int \cos\log x \; dx = x\cos\log x + \int \sin\log x \; dx.$$

For the second integral choose $u = \sin \log x$ and $dv = dx$.

$$\int \sin\log x \; dx = x\sin\log x-\int \cos\log x \; dx.$$

We then have

$$\int \cos\log x \; dx = x\cos\log x + x\sin\log x- \int \cos\log x \; dx.$$

$$= \frac{x}{2} \sin \log x + \frac{x}{2}\cos\log x + K.$$

Comment: shouldn't dv be dx and not 1 given your work?

Comment: @user983246 You are correct. I have a bad habit of leaving the $dx$ out.

Comment: how come you wrote log instead of ln? does it matter? are the same thing? I never understood it.

Comment: @user983246 In the context of the calculus, one often assumes that $\log x$ is the logarithm of base $e$. That is, $\log x$ and $\ln x$ mean the exact same thing. It is just a personal preference of notation.

Comment: I see. Just to clarify something from analyzing the first vdu, it seems the derivative of coslogx is -sinlogdx?

Comment: @user983246 Not exactly. The derivative of $\cos \log x$ is $-\sin\log x/x$ (chain rule). Since $v = x$, we have that $v \; du$ = $-\sin\log x$. Notice how the $x$ in the denominator of $du$ conveniently cancels with $v$.

Comment: okay I understand that part now. Now i just do not understand the last part with the fractions. How did that came about?

Comment: @user983246 The result follows from the fact that $x\cdot x^{-1}=1$.

Comment: Sorry but can you please help me with the first step? If $u=\cos(\ln(x))$ and $v=x$, doesn't $\int \dots = x\cos\log x + \int \dots$? and not $\int \dots = x\log\cos x + \int \dots$?

Comment: @Joao Thank you for noticing that.

Answer (score 8):

I think you're better off using $u$-substitution here. Setting $\ln x = u$, you get $du = \frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dx}{e^u}$, and so, $dx = e^u\,du$. Then, your integral becomes
$$\int \cos\left( \ln x \right) \, dx = \int e^u\cos u \, du,$$
which you can evaluate by using integration by parts twice.

Comment: Either way, one will need to twice integrate by parts so this is redundant.

Comment: Why redundant, @Gahawar ?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The substitution is unnecessary as one could directly apply two treatments of integration by parts to the original integrand without any added difficulty.

Comment: @Gahawar: I disagree. The substitution is useful in the sense that it makes clear that the integral can be computed by integration by parts.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\int \cos(\ln(x)) dx= \int \cos(u)xdu=\int  \cos(u)e^{u}du$

Answer (score 3):

$$ \int \cos(\ln x)\ dx $$
$$ \mbox{Let}\ u=\ln x \Rightarrow du=\frac{1}{x}dx\Rightarrow e^udu =dx $$
$$ \int e^u\cos u\ du $$
Now we can use the fact that
$$ \int e^{\alpha u}\cos(\beta u)\ du =\frac{e^{\alpha u}(\alpha\cos(\beta u)+\beta\sin(\beta u))}{\alpha^2+\beta^2}+C $$
To see that 
$$ \int e^u\cos u\ du= \frac{e^{u}(\cos u+\sin u)}{2} +C $$
Therefore 
$$ \int \cos(\ln x)\ dx = \frac{1}{2}x(\cos(\ln x)+\sin(\ln x)) +C $$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Another possible way starting with $$I=\int \cos(\ln(x)) dx= \int \cos(u)xdu=\int  \cos(u)e^{u}du$$ $$J=\int \sin(\ln(x)) dx= \int \sin(u)xdu=\int  \sin(u)e^{u}du$$ So $$I+iJ=\int e^{(1+i)u}du=\frac{1}{1+i}e^{(1+i)u}=\frac{1}{2}(1-i)e^u(\cos(u)+i\sin(u))$$ Take the real part as $I$ and the imaginary part for $J$.

Answer (score -3):

$$I = \int \cos(\ln x) = \int 1 \cdot \cos(\ln x)$$

Apply IBP with $1=v$, $\cos(\ln x)=u$.

$$I=\cos(\ln x) \cdot x- \int (-\sin(\ln x))x$$
Apply IBP again with $u=x$, $v=\sin(\ln x)$.
$$I=\cos(\ln x)x+ \sin(\ln x)x - \int \cos(\ln x)$$
$$2I=\cos(\ln x)x+ \sin(\ln x)x, \qquad
I=x/2(\cos(\ln x)+\sin(\ln x))$$

Comment: This is incorrect. The derivative of $u$ (first application) is $-\sin(\ln x) / x$. You are missing the $/x$ part.