# Integration by parts and choosing $u$ and $\mathrm{d}v$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\newcommand\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\int\cos(\ln(x))\diff x$$

I tried $u=\ln(x)$ but that didn't help. Should $u=\cos(\ln(x))$ and $v'=1$?

$$\int\sec^3(x)\diff x$$

Is there a trig identity to be used here?

$$\int e^{2x}(\sin(x))\diff x$$

I think I'm messing up the algebra-precalculus on this problem. Could I get a thorough break-down for this problem?

$$\int\arcsin(2x)\diff x$$
Could I get a thorough break-down of the steps? I think I'm messing up on my algebra.

Comment: Please, use correct formatting this will enable us to help you

Comment: Also, please refrain from asking multiple unrelated problems in a single question.

Comment: put mathematical expressions in $$ to be readable

Comment: LaTeX'd. (P.S. I put `$\newcommand\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}$` in the top so I could write `$\int f(x)\diff x$` for $\int f(x)\diff x$.

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957390/integrate-cos-lnx-dx/957395#957395 for the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}$For $\int\cos(\ln(x))\diff x$, use $u=\cos(\ln(x))$ and $\diff v=\diff x$. Thus, $\diff u=-\frac{\sin(\ln x)}x\diff x$ and $v=x$:
$$\int\cos(\ln(x))\diff x=uv-\int v\diff u=x\cos(\ln(x))+\int\sin(\ln(x))\diff x$$
Integrate by parts again, this time with $U=\sin(\ln(x))$ and $\diff V=\diff x$. Thus, $\diff U=\frac{\cos(\ln(x))}x$ and $V=x$:
\begin{align}
\int\cos(\ln(x))\diff x&=x\cos(\ln(x))+\int\sin(\ln(x))\diff x\\
&=x\cos(\ln(x))+\left(UV-\int V\diff U\right)\\
&=x\cos(\ln(x))+\left(x\sin(\ln(x))-\int\cos(\ln(x))\diff x\right)\\
&=x\cos(\ln(x))+x\sin(\ln(x))-\int\cos(\ln(x))\diff x
\end{align}
Adding that integral to both sides:
\begin{align}
2\int\cos(\ln(x))\diff x&=x\cos(\ln(x))+x\sin(\ln(x))+C\\
\int\cos(\ln(x))\diff x&=\frac12x\cos(\ln(x))+\frac12x\sin(\ln(x))+C
\end{align}

---

For $\int\sec^3x\diff x$, use $u=\sec x$ and $\diff v=\sec^2x\diff x$. Thus $\diff u=\tan x\sec x\diff x$ and $v=\tan x$:
$$\int\sec^3x\diff x=uv-\int v\diff u=\tan x\sec x-\int\tan^2 x\sec x\diff x$$
Using $\tan^2 x=\sec^2 x-1$:
\begin{align}
\int\sec^3x\diff x&=\tan x\sec x-\int(\sec^2x-1)\sec x\diff x\\
&=\tan x\sec x-\int(\sec^3x-\sec x)\diff x\\
&=\tan x\sec x-\int\sec^3x\diff x+\int\sec x\diff x\\
&=\tan x\sec x-\int\sec^3x\diff x+\ln|\tan x+\sec x|+C
\end{align}
where I used the formula for the integral of $\sec$. Adding $\int\sec^3\diff x$ to both sides:
\begin{align}
2\int\sec^3x\diff x&=\tan x\sec x+\ln|\tan x+\sec x|+C\\
\int\sec^3x\diff x&=\frac12\tan x\sec x+\frac12\ln|\tan x+\sec x|+C
\end{align}

Comment: For the third problem, you need to use integration by parts twice. For the last problem, you should probably make a substitution to turn it into $\int\arcsin(x)\diff x$. Then use $u=\arcsin x$ and $\diff v=\diff x$.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your textbook has some integration formulas you could use. The  first one is easily solved by letting $u=\ln x$ and using the formula for $$\int e^{ax} \cos (bx)\mathrm{d}x$$ or by integrating by parts with $f=\cos u, \mathrm{d}q=e^u \mathrm{d}u$

The second is the most usual example used on the reduction formula for 
$\int \sec^m(x) \mathrm{d}x$

Well, the third requires a usual trick(Assuming the integrand is $e^{2x} \sin x$), you integrate twice by parts, setting $h$ the trigonometric, $dv$ the exponential, your initial integral will reapear somewhere, separate it in LHS, the RHS is easily calculated

Last but not least, substitute $b=2x$ then integrate by parts with $j=\sin^{-1} (x), \mathrm{d}t=\mathrm{d}b$

Used so many variables to avoid confusion, not really sure if I actually avoided or created more confusion.

Comment: A reason for the downvote? Am I wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

For the first integration you can go in the following manner:

$\int{\cos({\ln{x}})}dx+i\int{\sin({\ln{x}})dx}=\int{e^{i\ln{}x}dx}=\int{(e^{\ln{x}})^i}dx=\int{x^i}dx=\frac{1}{i+1}x^{i+1}=\frac{1-i}{2}xx^i=\frac{1-i}{2}x(e^{i\ln{x}})=\frac{1-i}{2}x(\cos{\ln{x}}+i\sin{\ln{x}})$

So $\int{\cos({\ln{x}})}dx=\Re{(\int{\cos({\ln{x}})}dx+i\int{\sin({\ln{x}})dx}})=\Re{(\frac{1-i}{2}x(\cos{\ln{x}}+i\sin{\ln{x}}))}=\frac{x}{2}(\cos{(\ln{x})}+\sin{(\ln{x})})$

Answer (score 0):

For the second integration you can go in this manner:

$\int{\sec^3x}\space dx=\int\frac{1}{\cos^3x}dx=\int\frac{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}{\cos^3x}dx=\int\frac{dx}{\cos{x}}dx+\int\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^3x}dx$

Consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{\cos{x}}$, then we have:

$f'(x)=\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos^2x}$ and $f''(x)=\frac{1+\sin^2x}{\cos^3x}$

So we have $\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos^2x}=\int{\frac{1+\sin^2x}{\cos^3x}}dx=\int{\frac{dx}{\cos^3x}}+\int{\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^3x}dx}=\int\frac{dx}{\cos{x}}dx+2\int\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^3x}dx$

We know that $\int{\sec{x}\space dx}=\ln{|\sec{x}+\tan{x}|}$, hence

$\int\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^3x}dx=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos^2x}-\ln{|\sec{x}+\tan{x}|})$

So $\int{\sec^3x}\space dx=\ln{|\sec{x}+\tan{x}|}+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos^2x}-\ln{|\sec{x}+\tan{x}|})$

Answer (score 0):

For the third integral:

$\int{e^{2x}\sin{x}}\space dx=\Im{(\int{e^{2x}e^{ix}dx})}=\Im{(\int{e^{(2+i)x}}dx)}=\Im{(\frac{1}{2+i}e^{(2+i)x})}=\Im{(\frac{2-i}{5}e^{2x}(\cos{x}+i\sin{x}))}=e^{2x}(\frac{2}{5}\sin{x}-\frac{1}{5}\cos{x})$